# Conditional Compilation using UglifyJS + GruntJS

Tags: javascript, conditional-compilation, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I'm using [grunt-bbb](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb) for a JavaScript project I'm working on. I'd love to use conditional compilation using grunt's support for UglifyJS, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm trying to pass a `defines` option to uglify task, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My grunt.js file looks like:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        // ... config options ...

        uglify: {
            "mangle": {
                "defines": {"DEBUG": false}
            }
        },

        // ... more configs ...

    });

    // ... custom tasks ...

    grunt.registerTask("release", "default min mincss");
};
```

I've tried to add an `except` property to the `mangle` object as well, and that doesn't seem to work either (it still mangles the file...) UglifyJS is obviously being run, but it doesn't seem like it's getting the options passed in. I've dug through the code as well and when I `console.log(grunt.config('uglify'));` I get

```
{ mangle: { defines: { DEBUG: false } } }
```

which looks correct to me...

Any thoughts???

Comment: Tried the same thing, didn't work for me either...

Comment: Although other mangle options work, for example `mangle: {except: ['$']}` will leave the dollar symbol without renaming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/issues/426) to Grunt and aparently the problem is inside Uglify (the way the `defines` parameter is actually handled contradicts the docs).

This follwing code works:

```
uglify: {
  mangle: {
    defines: {
      DEBUG: ['name', 'true']
    }
  }
}
```

[Passed this to Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/issues/460).

Answer (score 4):

This is what currently works for me:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    compress: {
      global_defs: {
        APP_DEBUG: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

putting it in the compress option works, in this case it will set `APP_DEBUG=false`
I got this fix from here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/12